# How to align all vertices so that they would be lying on one plane?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, vertex-groups

Sometime faces have vertices that not aligned in one plane. 
For example if I have this (face should be flat here):

[image]

It rather should be like that:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of ways you could do this:

*Method 1*

- Select your face
- Change the 'Transform Orientation' to 'Normal'
  [image]
- Hit 'S' to scale
- Double-hit 'Z' to scale along the face's normal
- Type 0
- Hit enter

*Method 2*

- Add a new plane (single face)
- Rotate it as desired to define your belonged normal axis
- Again change your Transformation Orientation to Normal
- Create your custom orientation in the right-3dview-panel
  [image]
- Rename it and use it in the same way as 'Method 1'

Comment: The only problem with these methods is they don't produce the even/regular planes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it flat horizontally set the *3D cursor* as a *pivot point*, select the vertex which is lying on a grid floor and snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*) .Then select the non aligned one and press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>.
[image]

If you want do it like in your second picture duplicate the non alligned edge in *Edit Mode* and snap it to the opposite part of a plane (click the magnet icon, snap element type- *Vertex*), then merge the vertices as pictured below (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>-->*At Last*). Finally select the whole mesh and *remove doubles* (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*).
[image]